# How can R register SensorEventListener for all Sensors

Tags: orientation, accelerometer, sensors

When I study something about sensor, I find that when I use `sensorlistener` (here in my code its `mysensorlistener`) to register all the sensors in my device, it could get what I need. And if I change the listener to `sensoreventlistener` (in my code its `mysensoreventlistener`), it can only get accelerometer data.

I wonder if I could get all the data, just register one `sensorevevtlistener`.

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.testaccelerometer;


import com.example.testaccelerometer.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AccelerometerReader extends Activity {


    TextView atvx;
    TextView atvy;
    TextView atvz;
    TextView otvx;
    TextView otvy;
    TextView otvz;
    SensorManager mySensorManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.disp);
        atvx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.atvx);
        atvy = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.atvy);
        atvz = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.atvz);
        otvx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.otvx);
        otvy = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.otvy);
        otvz = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.otvz);
        mySensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mySensorManager.unregisterListener(mySensorEventListener);
        //mySensorManager.unregisterListener(aSensorEventListener);
        //mySensorManager.unregisterListener(oSensorEventListener);
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //mySensorManger.registerListener(mySensorListener, SensorManager.SENSOR_ALL,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mySensorManager.registerListener(mySensorEventListener, mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ALL), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        //mySensorManager.registerListener(aSensorEventListener, mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        //mySensorManager.registerListener(oSensorEventListener, mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        super.onResume();
    }
    /*private SensorListener mySensorListener = new SensorListener(){

        public void onAccuracyChanged(int sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(sensor){
            case SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER:
                atvx.setText("X轴方向的加速度：" + values[0]);
                atvy.setText("Y轴方向的加速度：" + values[1]);
                atvz.setText("Z轴方向的加速度：" + values[2]);
                break;
            case SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION:
                otvx.setText("X轴方向的角速度：" + values[0]);
                otvy.setText("Y轴方向的角速度：" + values[1]);
                otvz.setText("Z轴方向的角速度：" + values[2]);
            }
        }


    };*/
    private SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float[] values1;
            float[] values2;
            switch(event.sensor.getType()){
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                values1 = event.values;
                atvx.setText("X轴方向的加速度：" + values1[0]);
                atvy.setText("Y轴方向的加速度：" + values1[1]);
                atvz.setText("Z轴方向的加速度：" + values1[2]);
                System.out.println("run....accele");
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION:
                values2 = event.values;
                otvx.setText("X轴方向的角速度：" + values2[0]);
                otvy.setText("Y轴方向的角速度：" + values2[1]);
                otvz.setText("Z轴方向的角速度：" + values2[2]);
                System.out.println("run....orien");
                break;
            }

        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    /*
     * test
     */
    /*private SensorEventListener aSensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float[] values1;
            if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
                values1 = event.values;
                atvx.setText("X轴方向的加速度：" + values1[0]);          //accelerometer
                atvy.setText("Y轴方向的加速度：" + values1[1]);
                atvz.setText("Z轴方向的加速度：" + values1[2]);
                System.out.println("run....accele");
            }

        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };*/
        /*private SensorEventListener oSensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float[] values1;
            if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION){
                values1 = event.values;
                otvx.setText("X轴方向的角速度：" + values1[0]);         //orientation
                otvy.setText("Y轴方向的角速度：" + values1[1]);
                otvz.setText("Z轴方向的角速度：" + values1[2]);
                System.out.println("run....orien");
            }

        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };*/
}
```

when i surf the internet ,some guys say that the SensorEventListener can not use TYPE_ALL to register all the sensors,but it can use it to get sensorlist.
like code here:

```
//  注册加速度传感器
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

        //  注册磁场传感器
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

        //  注册光线传感器
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

        //  注册方向传感器
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to register all sensors to the same listener I would try something like:

```
List<Sensor> sensors = mySensorManager.getSensorList( Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER  );
for(int i = 0; i < sensors.lenght(); i++) {
  mySensorManager.registerListener(mySensorListener, sensors[i], SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}
```

And then when reading the info use a switch like:

```
this.mySensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
    int type = sensor.getType();
    switch (type) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            doSomethingInteresting();
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION:
                doSomethingInteresting();
        break;
    case ....:
                ......
                ......
            default:
        break;
         }
}
};
```

The code isn't perfect so please do not just cut and paste it into yours because I don't think it'll compile.

Answer (score 0):

furthermore, do not forget to unregister when application gets invisible, otherwise battery drains. (sensorManager needs to be a class variable to be visible inside method)

```
   @Override
protected void onStop() {        
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(mysel);
    super.onStop(); //now use super method
    finish();
}
```